# How can I pass multiple values as the IN parameter into a stored procedure?

Tags: linq

In stored procedure, I pass values using the `IN` clause. I get these values by selecting checkboxes.

I get the checkboxes by using a foreach loop and `.selecteditem.text`. This produces a string like `"1, 2"`
.

By passing that string into the stored procedure, the string gets wrapped in quotes. The problem is, that stored procedures doesn't accept those double quotes in the `IN` clause.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Please don't include your email address in public posts. It's not asking for help, it's asking for trouble. Also try clarifying your question and title. It's not really clear as to what you're asking.

Comment: thanks for your comment ,sorry for my mistake,,i post my question first time

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = "1,2";
var splitString = t.Split(',');
//splitString[0] will be "1" and splitString[1] will be "2"
```

You can then use Convert.ToInt32 on splitString[0] or [1] as you need for your stored procedure.